# Teradata and Arcgis Server 10.1 or 10.2

Tags: arcgis-server, teradata

We are in plan to develop a Web app which shows the location of business units on the map and few analysis like buffer analysis and showing heatmaps.

Our data will be in Teradata.  We are planning to use ESRI suite.  AS per the ESRI site, ArcGIS 10.2 can connect to Teradata st_geometry type (after installing few drivers).

Since Arcmap is able to connect teradata geoemtry columns, whehter we can create mxd and publish as map service  (feature service not required).

any one have worked in in this combo Arcgis server and Teradata? Pls. give your suggestions, whether you have faced or not faced any issues ?